# Display one second latitude and longitude grid lines on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to display one second latitude and longitude grid lines on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a graticule script at https://github.com/myshen/google-maps-v3-earth-map-type/blob/master/graticule.3.js

A demo and possible the [latest graticule v3 script version](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/v3_ll_grat.js) are at http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/ll_grat_v3_demo.htm. **Depending** on your **zoom level** the latitude and longitude grid lines are drawn with more or less detail.

There is another version of the graticule script at https://github.com/alexcheng1982/google-maps-gridlines/blob/master/src/google-maps-gridlines.js. No idea what is fixed there.

This is not exactly what you want, because the seconds are still displayed in decimal values. It is a matter of extending the graticule script `_.prototype.decToLonSex` and `_.prototype.decToLatSex` functions to also calculate the seconds in their sexagesimal value and to change `var decmins` and `var sexmins` to match exactly one second (=1÷60≅0.0166667).

I did adapt the graticule script to display the grid at 0.0005 degrees precision in most detailed view. Your request for a 1 second grid is almost equivalent to a grid at 0.000277778 degrees, which comes close. For inspiration have at look at this **more detailed grid** demo at http://crashplan.probackup.nl/stiphout/google-maps-with-coordinate-grid.html

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article, where was roughly explained how to prepare the grid lines in any location on the World.

http://mkrgeo-blog.com/how-to-show-coordinate-grids-in-google-earth-and-google-maps/

Comment: Since the images require a login, a short description here would be helpful.

Comment: Hi,

I know the problem, all comes from WP migration. I'll fix it and let U know. Thanks

Comment: @CWHolemanII try now please. I have restored this article recently.
Rgds,

Comment: @MKR the link doesn't work now.

Comment: Really? I've tried and it's fine. Try now please.